# jQuery zclipboard Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, zclip

Trying to get zclip to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.copy').zclip({
    path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:function(){return $('.macro').val();}
});

// The link with ID "copy-dynamic" will copy the current value
// of a dynamically changing input with the ID "dynamic"

});
```

now I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'data' @ jquery.zclip.js line 286

```
 $(this.domElement).data('zclipId', 'zclip-' + this.movieId);
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java. Removing the tag.

Comment: Can u add ur HTML markup to the question.Do u have any other browser errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/SEkfG/)

Add jQuery and zClip to your document.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.strategiqcommerce.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.1/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
```

attach zClip to the element which will become your "copy button".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.copy').zclip({
    path: 'http://cdn.strategiqcommerce.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.1/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
        return $('.macro').val();
    }
});
});
```

HTML Markup

```
<a href="#" class="copy">Copy</a>
<textarea rows=3 class="macro" placeholder="Type text that is to copied and click copy"></textarea>
<textarea rows=3 placeholder="Paste copied text and check"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm using ipboard, and have everything referenced correctly (or so it seems). Ipboard also uses prototype (hence the jQuery(document.ready(function($) {

Comment: Can u add ur HTML markup to the question.Do u have any other browser errors?